Extract fonts from text generating website
The "fancy text generator website" takes a text input and outputs it into different fonts.
I would like to extract the fonts used.
I don't know anything about HTML i searched around in the source code to try and find the fonts.
I also tried the network tab in devtools and filtered for fonts.

did you mean you want to get the font file (.ttf, .woff2)?

They're not fonts but unicode characters. :)
Here's how it’s done...
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
</head>

<body onload="alert(GetUnicodeText('We are not fonts!',1));">

<script type="text/javascript">

//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

function GetUnicodeText(Text,Style){
const T=[
'0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ',
'',
'',
'0123456789ℎ',
'0123456789',
'0123456789',
'0123456789',
'0123456789ℭℌℑℜℨ',
'0123456789',
'ℂℍℕℙℚℝℤ',
'0123456789ℯℊℴℬℰℱℋℐℒℳℛ',
'0123456789',
'0123456789ᴀʙᴄᴅᴇғɢʜɪᴊᴋʟᴍɴᴏᴘǫʀsᴛᴜᴠᴡxʏᴢABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ',
'0',
'0123456789ɐqɔpǝɟƃɥıɾʞןɯuodbɹsʇnʌʍxʎz∀qϽᗡƎℲƃHIſʞ˥WNOԀὉᴚS⊥∩ΛMXʎZ',
'0123456789ᗩᗷᑕᗪEᖴGᕼIᒍKᒪᗰᑎOᑭᑫᖇᔕTᑌᐯᗯ᙭YᘔᗩᗷᑕᗪEᖴGᕼIᒍKᒪᗰᑎOᑭᑫᖇᔕTᑌᐯᗯ᙭Yᘔ',
'０１２３４５６７８９ａｂｃｄｅｆｇｈｉｊｋｌｍｎｏｐｑｒｓｔｕｖｗｘｙｚＡＢＣＤＥＦＧＨＩＪＫＬＭＮＯＰＱＲＳＴＵＶＷＸＹＺ',
'0123456789ꋬꃳꉔ꒯ꏂꊰꍌꁝ꒐꒻ꀘ꒒ꂵꋊꄲꉣꆰꋪꇙ꓄꒤꒦ꅐꉧꌦꁴꋬꃳꉔ꒯ꏂꊰꍌꁝ꒐꒻ꀘ꒒ꂵꋊꄲꉣꆰꋪꇙ꓄꒤꒦ꅐꉧꌦꁴ',
'⓪①②③④⑤⑥⑦⑧⑨ⓐⓑⓒⓓⓔⓕⓖⓗⓘⓙⓚⓛⓜⓝⓞⓟⓠⓡⓢⓣⓤⓥⓦⓧⓨⓩⒶⒷⒸⒹⒺⒻⒼⒽⒾⒿⓀⓁⓂⓃⓄⓅⓆⓇⓈⓉⓊⓋⓌⓍⓎⓏ'];

const Symbols=[...T[Style]]; var S='', n=0;
for(var i=0; i<Text.length; i++){n=T[0].indexOf(Text.charAt(i)); if(n>-1){S+=Symbols[n];} else {S+=Text.charAt(i);}} 
if(Style==14){S=S.split('').reverse().join('');} return S;}
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

</script>
</body>
</html>

Have fun!
A little explanation as to how this is possible:
If you go through the Unicode character range you'll find that it's about 10,000 characters long and along the way as you explore them you'll find many interesting (A..Z) characters some of which can be used to simulate a new font as I've done in the code above.
Here's an excellent site for exploring Unicode characters…
Site
